# PHP. How to get REAL IP via adobe flash?

Tags: php, ip-address, flash

How do you know the real ip address using PHP and a adobe flash player?

I go to the website ip-score.com through socks5, but he also sees soks5 and through the flash player determines my real ip.

Comment: What exactly are you talking about? You are mentioning two or three technologies that have nothing to do with each other really. At which point do you want to get the IP address?

Comment: if you are connecting using a TCP socket don't you have to have his IP already? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that on windows, the Flash Player uses the internet explorer proxy settings, that you can configure in "Internet Options". So even if you set up a proxy in your browser, unless your browser is IE, they can still see you coming from your real location via Flash.

Another thing to consider is that most proxies will send your real IP in a custom header like [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For). That means you can grab the real IP of the client via that header as well, Flash or no Flash.